# Update object every second with useState hook

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, use-effect, use-state

I am generating a random number every 2 seconds and checking if my state object, data, has this number as a key. If so, then increment the value otherwise insert it into the object as a new field with a default value of 1. However, whenever the random number function runs, my state object, data, is empty so data.hasOwnProperty is always false. Why is this the case?

```js
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    //INTERVAL TO GENERATE RANDOM NUMBER EVERY 2 SECONDS
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      generateRandomStock();
    }, 2000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  //GENERATES A RANDOM NUMBER AND UPDATES THE STATE 
  const generateRandomStock = () => {
    const randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1).toString();
    console.log(data)
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(randNumber)) {
      console.log("has");
      setData((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        [randNumber]: prevState[randNumber] + 1,
      }));
    } else {
      console.log("does not have");
      setData((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        [randNumber]: 1,
      }));
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `generateRandomStock` function creates a closure with initial `data` value. That's always an empty object `{}`. You can access the `data` received to the callback function to `setData method where it gives updated values.

Try like below

```
  const generateRandomStock = () => {
    const randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1).toString();
    setData((prevData) => {
      console.log(prevData);
      if (prevData.hasOwnProperty(randNumber)) {
        return {
          ...prevData,
          [randNumber]: prevData[randNumber] + 1
        };
      } else {
        console.log("does not have");

        return {
          ...prevData,
          [randNumber]: 1
        };
      }
    });
  };
```

[image: Edit wizardly-brattain-ycquuj]

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `generateRandomStock` function as a dependency in `useEffect` hook.
Since this function uses the `data` value, its content is updated when the `data` value is updated.

```
const [data, setData] = useState({});

  //GENERATES A RANDOM NUMBER AND UPDATES THE STATE
  const generateRandomStock = () => {
    const randNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9 + 1).toString();
    console.log(data);
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(randNumber)) {
      console.log("has");
      setData((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        [randNumber]: prevState[randNumber] + 1
      }));
    } else {
      console.log("does not have");
      setData((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        [randNumber]: 1
      }));
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    //INTERVAL TO GENERATE RANDOM NUMBER EVERY 2 SECONDS
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      generateRandomStock();
    }, 2000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [generateRandomStock]);
```